# Finding spectrum of an integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Hello I'm wondering about how to deal with a situation like this:

I have $\mathcal{H} = L^2(0,\pi /2)$ and

\begin{equation}
Tf(x) = \int_0^{\pi/2} f(y)\cos(y)\sin(x)\,dy
\end{equation}

First I have to show that $T$ belongs to the space of finite rank operators , but this is trivial cause I can identify Im$(T)$ as span of $h(x) := \sin(x)|_{(0,\pi/2)}$ (right?). Then I have to determine its spectrum. So I know that 
\begin{equation}
\lambda \in \sigma_p (T) \Leftrightarrow\exists f\in L^2(0,\pi /2), f \neq 0 
\end{equation}

such that $Tf = \lambda f$. In this case I have

\begin{equation}
\sin(x)\int_0^{\pi/2} f(y)\cos(y)\,dy = \lambda f(x)
\end{equation}

Should I now derive both sides of equation, assuming $f \in C^1 (0,\pi/2)$?

Comment: You don't need to assume $f \in C^1$. For eignevectors you know that already because if $f$ is an eigenvector then $f \in \operatorname{Im}(T) = \operatorname{span}(\sin) \subset C^\infty$.

Comment: right.. but how should I isolate $f$?

Comment: Well try plugging $f = \alpha \sin$ into your equation since you know that's what $f$ must be if it is an eigenvector. What happens? (in fact you don't even need to know that $f \in C^1$ for this)

Comment: well I get $\lambda = \frac{\int_0^{\pi /2} f(y) cos(y)\,dy}{\alpha}$.. is that right?

Comment: Yes but you know $f(y)$ as well

Comment: I get $\lambda = 1/2$. can I conclude that this is the only value inside $\sigma_p(T)$?

Comment: Yes. What you've done is assumed that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $f$ and shown that $\lambda = 1/2$. Taking $f = \sin$ shows that $\lambda = 1/2$ is in fact an eigenvalue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86281/discussion-between-james-arten-and-rhys-steele).